# Facebook login error: can't find variable: Alert

Tags: react-native, facebook-graph-api, expo, facebook-authentication

I'm trying to authenticate users using facebook. I'm able to successfully ask for permission and authorize a user on the facebook platform, but then the app returns and error on redirect and produces the following error -> `Facebook Login Error: Can't find variable: Alert`. Yes I have `Alert` syntax in my facebook login method, but I simply cannot locate where this error is being triggered.

Has anyone experienced this before?

```
   facebookSignIn = async () => {
  try {
    const {
      type,
      token,
      expires,
      permissions,
      declinedPermissions,
    } = await Expo.Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync('<APP ID>', {
      permissions: ['public_profile'],
    });
    if (type === 'success') {
      // Get the user's name using Facebook's Graph API
      const response = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${token}`);
      Alert.alert('Logged in!', `Hi ${(await response.json()).name}!`);
      this.props.navigation.navigate('SenderHPP');
    } else {
      // type === 'cancel'
    }
  } catch ({ message }) {
    alert(`Facebook Login Error: ${message}`);
  }
};
```

Comment: did you import Alert from react-native? `import { Alert } from 'react-native'`

Answer (score 2):

Please try to add this line to the top.

```
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you import Alert from react-native?

first,

```
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
```

You're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Alert.alert is throwing this error. Replace it with "console.log" or simple alert.

Answer (score -1):

You should add this

`import *`as Facebook from 'expo-facebook';